Something about length contraction still feels off, is there any reason we talk about this effect in terms of length
When for example, a near lightspeed particle (or any inertial observer A) is approaching earth (or any inertial object B), we say that for the particle, the distances to earth are squished. How is this measureable and how is this seperable from speed.
The proper length of B can't be measured by A, unless A knows how fast B is going relative to it. Which it can't test either.
If we don't have any acceleration in the example, the only measurement A can do is to measure the difference in time between passing B's front and B's back, then computing the length would require knowing the relative speed of B, which A shouldn't have any access to.
For example, with the classic muon example, is there any difference between saying that the muon percieves earth as squished compared to saying that the muon percieves earth as travelling even faster?
It might be that both of these situations are equivalent, and it's just simpler to use length contraction than 'velocity dilation' in a single axis, but if theres some way to show that lengths contract and it's testably different from velocities dilating, I would like that.
Edit for clarity:
Would there be any testable difference between a universe where we know the lengths of objects, but velocities dilate, and a world where we know the relative velocities of objects, and but lengths contract.
It seems to me that they amount to the same thing.

One often assumes that each observer is equipped with an effectively factory-issued standardized set of tools ( a clock and a meterstick… or maybe just a light-clock).

I don't think the meterstick will help though, because of simultinaety?

A standardized meterstick  has a proper length of 1 meter.

Why can’t A know how fast B is going relative to A?

@robphy I never even allow students to have metersticks. Just clock, laser, and mirrors. Make them construct the Minkowski diagrams from scratch.

@robphy how could you use a meterstick to measure an object that you're travelling past

@naturallyInconsistent  I prefer light-clocks and radar measurements, in the sprit of Robb, Synge, Bondi, and Geroch (over the Taylor-Wheeler lattice of clocks and rods). My light-clock diamonds can handle all of the measurements of an inertial observer.

@Dale we assume that they can tell how fast they are going relative to one another, but i dont know why we are able to make that assumption, if velocities dilated instead of lengths contracting, i think that would have an identical effect.

@IfFishThenSticker You complained about not being able to measure the proper length of B… so I suggested all observers have a standard meterstick. So we now know the proper length of that standard… when B’s meterstick is in motion, we obtain its apparent-length from the worldlines of its endpoints. From that, apparent length, we can get the relative velocity or any of the relativistic factors relating B to our observer.

But they can measure it with radar or Doppler or a start and finish line or optics or other methods. It isn’t an assumption that they can tell how fast they are going. There are a bunch of well known ways to measure it

@robphy my bad, yeah you can measure the proper distance with it. But how would we measure with it while moving, I don't get that bit.

Oh wait i get it now. There's no way to measure it in the muon's case, technically, but for actual experiments, it wouldn't make sense to model a moving object as moving faster when moving fast, that's obviously just silly. Is there some way to award replies as the answer?

If the observer traveling with the muon had a camera as the Earth went by alongside him, he could simply take a photo of it, and it would show the Earth's dimension as far smaller in the  direction of travel than in the transverse direction. This is very different from seeing a spherical Earth moving "faster than expected"

@RC_23 Raw photographic data is insufficient, due to Terrell rotation.

You are very mistaken. There is a lot of equivalences, but you do not seem to have captured them correctly.

In the muon case, from the muon's perspective, it is the Earth (and space between Earth and muon) that is contracted. The muon is not moving; Earth is. Earth is travelling the shorter, contracted length, which is why it takes only a short time.
But from the Earth's perspective, the muon is having time dilation. Hence lifetime extension.
There is no such thing as velocity dilation.

As long as none of the particles are moving exactly at the speed of light in vacuum, they can all know each other's constant relative velocities. You just setup the measurement protocol and everybody can figure out each other's constant relative velocities.
Once you know the velocities, you can use whatever measured lengths and times, to figure out the proper times and proper lengths of everything. There is no mysteries.

I mean would there be any difference in predictions and observations if we settled on velocity dilation instead of length contraction. It seems to me like they are equivalent assertions.

What part of "There is no such thing as velocity dilation." do you not understand?

I believe you, I'm just looking for a quantifiable difference between a world where velocity dilation happens instead of length contraction, and this world. I suspect they amount to all the same results, and are equally valid models of the world.

There is no valid model of anything, if you insist upon relying upon non-existent things.

Yes also i now see why this model is stupid for any situation other than the muon one

You are overlooking two crucial points. Firstly, there are measurements that can be performed to distinguish a short object passing slowly from a long one passing quickly. Secondly, the concept of a velocity that increases with velocity is meaningless. To unpack the latter point, if there were some effect called velocity dilation, then an object's velocity would be some function of its velocity. That is, v=f(v). You might find it instructive to spin that equation around, to find f(v)=v. What does that tell you?

Answered through replies:
In the muon case, there's no difference between the earth moving extra fast vs lengths contracting. However when you run an experiment, this velocity dilation idea is stupid, since it would claim that the velocity of an object gets even higher when the objects velocity gets relativistic. Which is just babble, it makes sense to be able to claim definite relative velocities because thats the basis of how we calculate everything else in SR.
If I had a cannon that I know will shoot a ball at 10 m/s, I know the ball has diameter 1m. And I measure the time between the front and the back passing me as >0.1s, it would make sense to say that the length of the ball has contracted, instead of saying that somehow the 10 m/s has become >10 m/s. Otherwise there would be no point using the word "velocity" because a velocity would cause itself to be higher, you have to handle time and length independently.

You cannot be correct. It is Earth moving fast PLUS length contracting, in order to get the correct result. Constant relative velocities are very easy to measure, and is agreed between pairs of observers (and other observers can deduce their agreed values too), and so there CANNOT be velocity dilation in the first place.

Yeah I agree, the issue was that i was only considering the muon example, where the muon and the earth can't "agree" on anything or test each other. Because in that specific case, the formula is identical: time from mountain to ground = velocity/(length/lorentz) ----is same as---- time from mountain to ground = (velocity*lorentz)/(length)

Good; as long as you understand it is futile. You simply did not know that well-defined relative velocities in SR are absolute quantities. Now, the correct relations are that $$v=\frac{L/\gamma}{\tau}=\frac{L}{\gamma\tau}$$i.e. length contraction or time dilation, and no other possible choices.

thanks for your patience
